# How to decide which diffusion scheme is better for a block cipher design

Tags: block-cipher, diffusion, mds

There are several schemes that can be used to achieve the diffusion property in a block cipher. Schemes include MDS code, Bit permutation, Byte/ Nibble permutation, Diffusion Matrix, Diffusion Switching Mechanism. The amount of diffusion offered by these schemes seems to be a good criteria to choose the scheme.

As reference I have "On the Diffusion Property of Iterated Functions" (see [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/873.pdf)). In that document some degree of completeness is being calculated ($D_c$) that I do not understand.

Is there any strategy to quantify how much diffusion is achieved by the above mentioned diffusion schemes?

Comment: please specify your reference fully.

Comment: You can find the paper here  in the link https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/873.pdf